# ZAP Error [java.net.ConnectException]: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: proxy, zap, ctf

I am trying to connect to `http://challenge01.root-me.org/web-serveur/ch10/` in `Firefox` with `FoxyProxy` and `OWASP ZAP` and I got this error message

```
ZAP Error [java.net.ConnectException]: Connection refused (Connection refused)


Stack Trace:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:728)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:449)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:201)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.executeMethod(HttpSender.java:418)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.runMethod(HttpSender.java:653)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:609)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:585)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:573)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:478)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:448)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(ProxyThread.java:564)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(ProxyThread.java:335)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Then I tried to find out where the problem lies. I tried to do the same on the command line: When I call `curl http://challenge01.root-me.org/web-serveur/ch10/`, I get the correct result. But when I start `OWASP ZAP` and call the command `curl --proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 http://challenge01.root-me.org/web-serveur/ch10/`, I get the same error message.

Then I tried the same with another site from me `https://www.mysite.com`. I tried all the same things and I could connect to my site using `OWASP ZAP`.

So, what can I do to find out why it does not work with `http://challenge01.root-me.org/web-serveur/ch10/` but with `https://www.mysite.com`?

**Edit**

My proxy settings for `OWASP ZAP` are these

[image]

Comment: Please check and reply what are the proxy settings for Owasp-ZAP. i.e., if it redirecting to another proxy.

Comment: kindly update if there is an issue with proxy settings of zap

Comment: That screenshot shows the settings for the outside (or proxy to server side) of ZAP. The "Proxy" settings are under "Local Proxies".